# CrudRepository: find "Field" By "OtherField"

Tags: spring-data-jpa

To avoid writing query like this:

```
@Query("SELECT p.name FROM Person p WHERE p.email =:email")
String findNameByEmail(@Param("email") String email);
```

I would like to know if there is a way to write it without `@Query` annotation:

```
String findNameByEmail(@Param("email") String email);
```

I can't find anything like this and I am not sure if it is possible or if I am missing something.

Comment: I think you can't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) with one property:

```
public interface OnlyName {
    String getName();
}

OnlyName findByEmail(String email);
```